# IR Obstacle Sensor not executing code despite getting the right values

Tags: c++, arduino-uno

We're doing a project in school where we're supposed to make an autonomous robot that will search for another robot on a play field and try to push it off the board. The board has a black circle around it and the other parts are white.
The search function works fine and pushing objects off the board.
However the IR-sensor picks up the fact that it has reached the black edge but the code that's supposed to run when it does doesn't execute. I've tried different hierarchies in terms of which control comes first in the if-statement but nothing seems to work.

```
#include <NewPing.h>
#define TRIGGER_PIN  14
#define ECHO_PIN     15
#define MAX_DISTANCE 70

NewPing DistanceSensor(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE);

// motor one
int enA = 10;
int in1 = 9;
int in2 = 8;
// motor two
int enB = 5;
int in3 = 7;
int in4 = 6;
// IR-sensor
int obstaclePin = 4;  
int hasObstacle = HIGH; // HIGH MEANS NO OBSTACLE

void setup()
{
  // set IR-sensor pin to input
  pinMode(obstaclePin, INPUT);
  // set all the motor control pins to outputs
  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void driveFwd() {
  // turn on motor A
  digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
  // turn on motor B
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
  // set speed to 200 out of possible range 0~255
  analogWrite(enA, 255);
  analogWrite(enB, 255);
}

void driveBwd() {
  // now change motor directions
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);  
  digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW); 
  analogWrite(enA, 255);
  analogWrite(enB, 255);
}

void driveStop() {
  // now turn off motors
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);  
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
}

void driveTurn() {
  //Motor A, forward
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
  //Motor B, backward
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
  //Turn on full speed
  analogWrite(enA, 255);
  analogWrite(enB, 255);
}

void loop()
{
  unsigned int cm = DistanceSensor.ping_cm();

 //Main code for the behaviors depending on information from the IR- and distance sensor

 if (cm == 0) {
   driveTurn();
 }
 else if (cm > 0) {
   driveFwd();      
 }
 else if (hasObstacle == HIGH) {
   driveStop();
   while (hasObstacle == HIGH) {
     driveBwd();
   }
 }   
}
```

Comment: Careful, hasObstacle it's always set to HIGH. (a recommendation, why don't you use true and false instead of HIGH and LOW for this variable, as it represent a logical statement)

Comment: I also do not know how your sensor returns the distances, but cm == 0 is a pretty tight condition, what if it is equal to 0.00001

Comment: If it's 0.00001 then it's > 0 so it should execute the else if. It's an ultrasonic sensor that measures the distance.

Comment: As for the variable set to HIGH - HIGH is only the case when it doesn't get much or any light reflected back from the IR diode. So that should only apply when it reaches the black edge.

Comment: but I mean, it will rarely be == 0, it will always be more or less, it's rare that a sensor gives you an exact value, you should be careful with that. The usual technique is to use ranges, the == condition is very very strong, it would be very rare that "driveTurn" gets executed

Comment: you should better do something like "if (cm <= min_distance)" and "if(cm > min_distance)" That would be safer.

Comment: what I'm saying with the HIGH keyword, is that it could would look closer to the way we speak (thus easier to understand code) if you use true: "if (hasObstacle == true)". With high it will work, but it's just a style tip.

Comment: The turn and drive functions both work as they should though. It's the IR sensor that's the issue